# Detect device moving detail

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am doing a demo in which when I move device like on top-left, top-right,top-center and bottom-right, bottom-left, bottom-center, center-right, center-left this type of movement I need to detect so that I am looking for accelerometer and gyroscope sensor. Am I going on the right track or not?

Do you have any demo or any link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes accelerometer would be a good option to detect the motion of the phone

You need to override the onSensorChange even in your activity in order to detect accelerometer values.

```
public void onSensorChange(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
  Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

  if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
      float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
      float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
  }
}
```

Get started from here

[Sensors Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)

[Using the Accelerometer on Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)

[SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Also check out [this](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/88) page for a collection of android sensors library.